# Find rows that have both boolean in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle11 table like this:

```
id          name       have_child
----------- ---------- ------------
1           Alison     N
2           Mary       N
3           Meg        Y
4           Mary       N
5           Meg        N
```

where have_child is probably Boolean = Y/N.
I want to do query to list wrong behavior where one name can be Y and N - like Meg:

```
id          name       have_child
----------- ---------- ------------
3           Meg        Y
5           Meg        N
```

As a result I want to list entire rows.

I do not want to list proper duplicates - like Mary:

```
id          name       have_child
----------- ---------- ------------
2           Mary       N
4           Mary       N
```

I know how to count particular names and list what names appears more than 1 time like this:

```
SELECT name from table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a way:

```
select id, name, have_child
from (
    select t.*,
           count(distinct have_child) over (partition by name) as num
    from yourTable t
    )
where num > 1
```

The inner query simply lists all the records of the table, adding a column which gives the number of different values of `have_child` for the same `name`.
The external one simply filters for rows in which this number is greater than 1.